# ASCII increment with defined range

Tags: sql-server, algorithm

Client wants to append a field with a literal increment based on a count.

The range goes from '*aa*' to '*zz*'.

'*aa*' represents a count of **1** and '*zz*' represents the max value in the range:  **676**

I have sql that ***almost*** works but would appreciate an expert eye to get me over the last hurdle.

```
--Constants
DECLARE @START_ASCII INT = 97
DECLARE @ASCII_OFFSET INT = 1
DECLARE @ALPHABET_LETTER_COUNT INT = 26

--Variables
DECLARE @RecordCount INT = 0
DECLARE @FirstLetter VARCHAR(1) = NULL
DECLARE @SecondLetter VARCHAR(1) = NULL

SET @RecordCount = 1 --Range is 1 to 676 (e.g. 'aa' to 'zz')

SET @FirstLetter = CHAR(round(@RecordCount / @ALPHABET_LETTER_COUNT, 2, 1) + @START_ASCII) 
SET @SecondLetter = CHAR((((@RecordCount - @ASCII_OFFSET) % @ALPHABET_LETTER_COUNT) + @START_ASCII)) 

SELECT @FirstLetter + @SecondLetter
```

The problem with the above sql involves the first letter.  It works till the end of the alphabet is reached for the second letter.  For example, at a count of **26**, I expect '*az*', but instead get '*bz*'.

I want to keep the SQL small and tight (e.g. no CASE statements).  Is there a small tweak I can make to the above code so that it will work?

Or, if there is just a smarter way to skin this cat, I'd like to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think of this as computing the base-26 representation of `@RecordCount-1` (range 0 to 675). Then map the two-digits of the base-26 number to the ASCII characters:

```
SET @FirstLetter = CHAR(floor((@RecordCount-1) / @ALPHABET_LETTER_COUNT) + @START_ASCII)
SET @SecondLetter = CHAR(((@RecordCount-1) % @ALPHABET_LETTER_COUNT) + @START_ASCII)
```